# How to handle Selenium crashing in Javascript? Exception caught and handled but program still crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, error-handling

I've had a lot of issues with Selenium running just fine for a long time but then suddenly crashing with the following error message:

```
A critical error was thrown while processing
        https://www.testtesttest.com/norwegian-english/snakk. Error was WebDriverError: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0
/opt/narjetas/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

WebDriverError: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/opt/narjetas/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/opt/narjetas/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:587:13)
    at Executor.execute (/opt/narjetas/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:515:28)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  remoteStacktrace: ''
}
```

To account for this I wrapped my returned promise with a catch block:

```js
getUrl(req.params.url, driver).then(html => {
    res.send(`${html}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.info("INFO: Exiting driver.");
        
        driver.quit().catch(() => {
            console.error("ERROR: Failed to quit driver.");
        })
    }, 1000);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`A critical error was thrown while processing 
    ${req.params.url}. Error was ${error}`);
    res.send('');
});
```

I see from the beginning of the error message it is correctly running my catch block and printing the error but then Selenium brings the program down anyway.

My question is, how do I handle this Selenium error such that the program can continue? I'm also open to improving how I handle Selenium but it's not clear to me how to troubleshoot that error - it never happens in the same place or the same input.

### Other Notes

With Selenium, I have also seen this error before but it is again not repeatable. I have tried rerunning the same input that gave it to me and it never pops up:

```
(node:1156709) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

### Platform Info

```
[root@lab ~]# cat /etc/*-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)

[root@lab ~]# firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 91.13.0esr
```

Comment: As the code is, you're repeatedly calling driver.quit().  That might be causing the max listener error.  Once the driver has been disposed of it'll be a null pointer but it'll take a little time for the driver to close the browser and dispose of itself.    Not sure why you use a get() and then quit the driver, though...

Comment: Longer story on why I'm doing that but while I'm willing to look into that, if it were the problem, wouldn't I have seen the output from `console.error("ERROR: Failed to quit driver.");`?

Comment: probably some kind of scope or delayed throw issue with the closure/anonymous function.

Comment: Seems like you should be returning something ,too...  I'd axe the settimeout and return something for your promise after calling .quit().  (I've never used Selenium in Javascript, so I'm doing a lot of guessing here... )

Comment: Honestly, wouldn't recommend it. This is a personal project but I'm super glad it isn't production. Python - Selenium: easy to use, straightforward, plenty of code examples if you get stuck... Javascript.... ehhhhhhh it has been kinda rough. Very unstable *especially* on Linux (I still can't get chromedriver to work). The return happens before I exit the driver. I added the timeout just to give it some time after the last thing that happened and when I killed it.

Comment: Really, the main question I'm trying to get answered is why the heck that catch block isn't actually handling the error. I can't figure out how Selenium is managing to kill the program even when its exception is caught and handled.

Comment: I didn't notice that you're not using setTimeout as a polling loop...  setTimeout will return a unique id immediately... so I guess the promise returns before .quit() method ever runs.  Whatever that res.send() call does may also return a promise...  so I'd be very careful to make sure nothing runs asynchronous... consider using callbacks when using anonymous functions to chain things when .then() isn't used.

Comment: basically you'll want to ensure that everything returns something whether you are using a .then or a callback.  (unless you use "await"??)  SetTimeout seems like it should be avoided.  I believe there are some driver methods that return null, but I guess that would be a returned promise?